# actionscript 3 event.target

Tags: actionscript-3, events, target, movieclip

I have a movie clip named button1 and in this movie clip
there is a dynamic text named txt

```
 public function mouse_down(event:MouseEvent)
      {
      if(event.target==button1)
      {
      ...//this only recognizes when i click the button without intersecting the dynamic text area
      }
      if(event.target==button1||event.target==button1.txt)
      {
      ...//this works
      }
```

i would like to know why it dosen't recognize clicks made in the area that contains the dynamic click if i don't specify it, because txt is part of button1, so normally i would only need to check if the target is button1 but it dosen't work:i also have to check if the target is button1.txt

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`event.target` always points to the object the event originated from, even if it is nested in the object you added the listener to. Use `event.currentTarget` instead.

Check out [this blog post](http://mysticnomad.wordpress.com/2008/03/21/difference-between-eventtarget-and-eventcurrenttarget-properties-in-an-event-object/) to learn more.

Comment: The problem is that button1 is already located in a movie clip called main_menu so current target recognizes main_menu as the target

Comment: You could also set `mouseChildren = false` on button1, then the clicks will no longer be picked up by the text field.